# How to create custom location for add_filter?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, add-filter

I have a custom.php page in my Wordpress plugin within which I want to output the following in a certain location:

```
class Report_a_bug {

public function __construct() {

    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'report_button' ), 10, 1 );

}

public function report_button( $content ) {

    $content .= '<div class="report-a-bug">
                    <button class="show-form" data-post_id="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . 
                        __( 'Report a bug', 'reportabug' ) . 
                    '</button>
                    <textarea class="report-a-bug-message" placeholder="' . __( 'Describe what\'s wrong...', 'reportabug' ) . '"></textarea>
                    <p class="report-a-bug-response"></p>
                </div>';

    return $content;

}

}
```

Instead of using 'the_content' how can I tell it to place the code in a custom location by using:

```
new Report_a_bug();
```

**UPDATED CODE - STILL NO OUTPUT**

```
class Report_a_bug
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->custom_hook();
        add_action( 'custom_hook', array( $this, 'report_button' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    function custom_hook()
    {
        do_action('custom_hook');
    }

    public function report_button($content)
    {
        $content .= '<div class="report-a-bug">
        <button class="show-form" data-post_id="' . get_the_ID() . '">' .
            __('Report a bug', 'reportabug') .
            '</button>
        <textarea class="report-a-bug-message" placeholder="' . __('Describe what\'s wrong...', 'reportabug') . '"></textarea>
        <p class="report-a-bug-response"></p>
    </div>';

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Trying to call in page using `new Report_a_bug();`